# DHCP IPV6 Environment

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dhclient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DHCP IPV6 Environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/335351/dhcp-ipv6-environment)

in DHCPV4  for discover, request we mention the source ip as 0.0.0.0,what it could be the in DHCPv6.Similarly we mention the multicast address as 255.255.255.255 in DHCPv4 ,what could be the in DHCPv6.
When i am converting from DHCPV4 TO DHCPV6 ,tell me the changes need to take in the ip address and mac address differences.
If i use any relayagent what could be the difference if from v4.

I am new to networking.can you explain me .

thanks in advacne.

Ramulu Ponnam

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you read [the relevant RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3315)? It clearly mentions the multicast addresses `All_DHCP_Relay_Agents_and_Servers` (`FF02::1:2`) and `All_DHCP_Servers` (`FF05::1:3`).

And as source address, you take supposedly your link local address (`FE80:...`), which you have to negotiate and assign before.

Comment: It sounds like homework - I don't think he has read anything on this topic.